# REST URL Call throwing file not found exception

Tags: spring-mvc

Can anybody tell me what could be causing this exception?. Because it is working fine in testing environment and not in the live servers .

I tried checking the differences of test and existing prod war file, but i did not find any differences.

The major change I did was converted project from ANT to MAVEN,  but not sure how this is related to this exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8888/getreport
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.sample.SimpleTest.webcontroller.SimpleController.getreport(SimpleController.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Did you test the url with `curl` on live server? Do you get a valid response?

Comment: identified the issue and resolved . there was hidden exception in the service which lead to file found exception in the main application which calls the internal service. Thanks Sudhir !